# Is there a way to commit and push Git aliases to a repository?

Tags: git

I have a few global Git config scripts that I want to be present for anyone who'd like to clone some of my projects. Is there a way in Git to do this? If I understand correctly, local aliases are placed in `.git/config` which isn't version controlled.